# How to update a state object in the DOM from componentDidMount() (not componentDidUpdate())?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, dygraphs

I'm trying to conditionally show or not show per say a button based on data that I receive from clicking on a point. I realized that regular jquery functions to add a class don't really work in React. So I figured I could store strings in the state like

```
this.state: {
    hidden_components: {
        add_comment: "hide"
    }
}
```

This way I can conditionally show or hide a button by

```
<button className={this.state.hidden_components.add_comment}> Add Comment </button>
```

After the render() I have more or less:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.state.g = new Dygraph
  this.state.modal = new Modal 

  this.state.modal.setContent(use some ID here to reference a div that is hidden but will show up in the modal)

  const set_hidden_container = () => {
      // I'm just going to use this = notation instead of setState()
      // this is supposed to reset the 
      this.state.hidden_components = "hide"
      if (check_comment(this.state.points[at some index].value)) {
        this.state.hidden_components = "show"
      }
  }

  this.state.g.updateOptions( {

    pointClickCallback: (event, p) => {
      console.log("i clicked a point on the graph")
      this.setState({
        currentPoint: p
      })

      set_hidden_containers()

      // force update
      this.setState({
        currentPoint: p
      })

      // I want the modal to open a div of things that only show jsx based on logic in set_hidden_container()
      this.state.modal.open()
    }
  }

componentDidUpdate() {
  // logic goes here for like event listeners and anything that queries the DOM after initialization
}
```

Then in componentDidMount() I have a function that depending on the data received from clicking on a point I do the following:
1) reset all the classes stored in the state to "hide"
2) based on conditions set some of them to "show"
3) concatenate all the classes stored in the state with various styling classes

UPDATE: 
I've long since found an easier solution to this problem, however, I'm guessing some people might have similar issues. Therefore, I'll update this question with more psuedocode and a workaround: maybe someone down the line can solve this. This component is particularly frustrating to work with because I haven't been able to make it as modular as I want because of the particular library I'm working with. There are actually about a 1000 lines in this component (I know I know not good).

WORKAROUND:
For those of you who are having trouble with a component's lifecycle in dynamically setting parts of the DOM but don't want to use global variables to set classNames, jquery functions, or use react syntax to show components containing the content I recommend you do the following.

You can still have a set_hidden_container() set content dynamically, you just have to set things based on an id with innerHTML instead of setting a state object to be a string "show". The important thing is, however, that for every time you need to dynamically change content you reset these references to be empty as well as force an update. You can simply change the state of anything and then in componentDidUpdate() you can insert 1) a conditional to check if the innerHTML was actually set or not (since you're not always going to be displaying everything) and 2) within that conditional you can set whatever logic you want associated with the content showing on the page.

Comment: Can you add more of your code? Maybe make a simplified version if it's too long and convoluted. Right now you have paragraphs of text trying to explain your app flow but it's still pretty hard to visualize. If I understand correctly, your real problem is that you don't know how to reference an object declared in `componentDidMount` in other lifecycle methods?

Comment: Yes! That is a big problem. To be honest, I can do this so many different ways that this isn't actually obstructing my project but I really want to learn React thoroughly. And yes I think I'll try adding more code

Comment: To be honest, I think the solution to this makes this method not as versatile as I thought for any components that directly work with several parts of the React lifecycle. However, you have to move ALL relevant variables into the state object so that it can be globally referenced and then set conditionals for any eventlisteners or queries you are doing in the DOM so that it's only triggered when the DOM is set. Also this is annoying because I think you have to trigger state changes to update the component. In any case, I am not using this method because there is still one other problem.

Comment: State is not the only way to reference things inside React components. It is totally valid to save objects to the `this` variable outside of using state. Could you add more code to this post, even if it is simplified pseudo code to better exemplify your app's flow and what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AndyNoelker I updated the post I'm not sure if that makes things clearer. I need to set the foundation of the content I'm changing (such as the modal) and then change what's on that foundation depending on a pointClickCallBack function specific to the javascript library I'm using to generate the graph. If I move a minimum of what I just explained the entire graph will update resetting other parts I want to remain constant (for example if a user is zoomed in on a part of the graph).

Answer (score 1):

[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) is invoked immediately after a component is mounted.  If you want to set classNames based on clicks, I would put that logic in [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), which is invoked after updating occurs.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I add any parts/logic that needs to be updated regularly in Update() and any parts/logic that need to be mounted in Mount() I feel stupid

Comment: The problem with this however seems to be that since I initialize a graph object in componentDidMount() (it's in Mount because it references an id in the DOM) but I refer to that object to update it in Update so I get an error in the console saying: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateOptions' of null. Is there any way around this?

Comment: One other thing to note is that the object itself is global since I stored it in the state so I'm not sure why it says the the object is null? Doesn't componentDidMount() get initialized before componentDidUpdate()?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question.  `componentDidMount()` will be called when an instance of your component is being created.  `componentDidUpdate()` will be called if the props or state changes.  You should be able to store the graph object in the component's state by calling `setState()` in `componentDidMount()`, and then accessing it by `this.state.myObject` in `componentDidUpdate()` after a click is made.  Does that help, or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: I think I did not explain properly. But the componentDidMount() initializes a graph object and a modal object that is referenced to 1) get the point and it's data 2) have fields where you can edit the data in the modal. I thought initially that what you said would work but it only works if I can reference variables (the graph and modal objects) written in Mount() in Update() but unfortunately that seems to not be the case.